# how to retain values of forms which are in loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I am creating a project in which there is a loop of 3 forms form1->form2->form3->form1->form2->form3.... and loop stays until application is exit. Loop is made through a button. In form3 I have used interop.excel and copied data from a worksheet to an array which is done by selecting an name of excel file from the listbox.

Now the problem is that every time I go from form3 to form1 form3 looses focus and form2 always create a new instance of form3. So even my previous form3 is open it opens new form3.

I have seen and tried solution given on  [How can I loop through all the open instances of a particular form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646705/how-can-i-loop-through-all-the-open-instances-of-a-particular-form) and [Application.OpenForms.Count = 0 always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751554/application-openforms-count-0-always)
but it didn't help.

Is there a way that form2 can check if there is any instance of form3  or not and then take a decision to make new instance of form3 or give focus to previous form3 .

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [This Thread](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=152892)

```
Function IsUserFormLoaded(ByVal UFName As String) As Boolean 
Dim UForm As Object 

IsUserFormLoaded = False 
For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms 
    If UForm.Name = UFName Then 
        IsUserFormLoaded = True 
        Exit For 
    End If 
Next 
End Function 'IsUserFormLoaded
```

so for your needs you could do

```
If IsUserFormLoaded(UserForm3) Then
    'Code if it is open here
Else 
    'Code if it is NOT open here
End If
```