# .Net Winforms notify all open windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new to .Net Winforms, i generally work on either console apps or MVC.

I am developing a MDI WinForms application, and if I make a change in one (any) window, I need all other open MDI forms to refresh when the change has been made so they can also show the updated data.

How can this be achieved - In my old Delphi (v3) days, you used to "publish" a WM_USER type message and each form would have a "subscriber handler" that would then take the required action but that was a long time ago.

All the forms are slight variations of the data and a change in one form can affect the data in the others..

TYIA

Comment: Are all the Forms of the same type (if so, you can take reference from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646705/how-can-i-loop-through-all-the-open-instances-of-a-particular-form and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx)? Using that you can loop over all open forms, and call a Refresh() method (declare it as public).

Comment: No, the forms are not multiple instances of the same form, they are all slightly different.. but it would work in principle... Ideally.. I would only want to refresh forms if it uses the __type__ of data that's changed (e.g. all forms that are showing some sort of employee data)

Comment: Add an event to your MDI parent form, all children can subscribe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an event system between children and parent, which can be accomplished as follows:

- Create a base class for your child forms that contains an event to be raised when any data on the form is changed. Let's call it `FormChanged` event.
- Add an event to the Parent form to notify all children. Let's call it `ChildFormChanged` event.
- Upon instantiation of each child form, have the parent form subscribe to the `FormChanged` event of the child, AND have the new child form subscribe to the `ChildFormChanged` event of the parent form.
- The event handler for the `FormChanged` event in the parent form is just a pass-through function, that in turn raises the `ChildFormChanged` event, passing the information received from the child form causing the event to fire.
- The `ChildFormChanged` event can be handled in the base class for child forms via a virtual event handler (to handle generic items) that can be overridden in each child class (to handle specifics of each child form).

I wrote and commented an example app in C# and [posted it on Github](https://github.com/CoolBots/StackOverflowAnswers/tree/master/MDIFormRefreshAllChildren). Here's the relevant code:

Base child Form:

```
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FormChanged;

    public virtual void ProcessChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if((sender as Form) != this)
        {
            //Handle change
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyParent() => FormChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Parent form:

```
    public event EventHandler ChildFormChanged;

    public void NotifyAllChildren(object sender, EventArgs e)
        => ChildFormChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);

    //Child form creation function
    private void createNewFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MDIChildBase newChild = new MDIChild(); //Can be different child forms
        newChild.MdiParent = this;

        //Parent-child event subscription
        newChild.FormChanged += NotifyAllChildren;
        ChildFormChanged += newChild.ProcessChange;

        newChild.Show();
    }
```

Every child form must call `base.NotifyParent();` once any changes occur that you want to propagate to other child forms.

Comment: I am surmising that I could add information to the EventArgs (or a custom one) to specify type of change (employee / stock ) and then the react as appropriate in the child form

Comment: @ChrisHammond, absolutely, or declare your own delegate - I used `EventHandler` to make the example quick and easy to read, as many readers are familiar with this delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the windows messaging infrastructure. Explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage).

Comment: Bit of a sledgehammer with that ... Thought there might be something a little more seamless.