# Is there any other way to access open forms in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

```
 Application.OpenForms["formname"];
```

Is there any other way to access an open form. My application doesn't see this form although it is opened. I dont know why.

Comment: Is this "formname" is the name of the instance of the open form or is it the name of the class of the open form? Perhaps you could post your code here too, especially the one related to "formname"

Comment: Did you set the `name` of the form?

Comment: What does the OpenForms collection contain?

Comment: Have a look at all open forms: `MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Select(form => form.Name)));` can you find the required form?

Comment: Don't lose track of the form object you created.  [Or work around the bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3751748/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant you link is really useful. ;)

Comment: Isnt there any other way to access open forms?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't really necessary a name to get an open form.
You can get the form you want by index:

```
Form frm = Application.OpenForms[0] //Will get the main form
Form frm = Application.OpenForms[1] //Will get the first child
```

Forms in the OpenForms collection are ordered in the same way that you create it

Otherwise, an alternative is to save a reference to the form and then accessing it by this reference.

```
//Where you want to save the reference:
Form theForm;
//Where you create the form:
myClass.theForm = new MyForm();
//Where you want to get that form:
MessageBox.Show(myClass.theForm.Caption);
```

(myClass is the class that will hold your reference to the form, supposing you are accessing it from different classes)

(Also, see if you are affected by this:  [Application.OpenForms.Count = 0 always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751554/application-openforms-count-0-always?lq=1))

Comment: *Forms in the OpenForms collection are ordered in the same way that you create it* Is this documented?

Comment: @nawfal as we can see from the source:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,4833

a form is added to that collection on the form OnLoad event (with OpenFormsInternalAdd).

So the order should be guaranteed as long as we show forms in a sequential manner.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to firstly debug your code to check what is the `Form` actual name which you want to load:

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) {
    string name = form.Name; //check out this name!!
    //print, or anything else will do, you only want to get the name
    //note that you should be able to get any form as long as you get its name correct
}
```

And then, once you know what is wrong with your code, simply do:

```
Form form = Application.OpenForms[name]; //use the same name as whatever is available according to your debug
```

To get your `form`.

To check more on the possible bugs, See [Hans Passant's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751554/application-openforms-count-0-always/3751748#3751748)

Answer (score 1):

You have to instanciate first a `Form`. after that you have access to it:

```
Form1 formname = new Form1();
Application.Run(formname);

// access to form by formname.yourproperty
```

Comment: What does it mean? Application.Run(formname)?

Comment: Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread, and makes the specified form visible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To access the form using this property your `form` must have a [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx).

Remember its not the instance name nor the the form Text:

```
  Form1 f1 = new Form1();    //not "f1" is the "Name"  
  f1.Text = "it is title of the form"; //neither "Text" is the "Name"
  f1.Name= "its the name"; //it is the "Name"
```

Sample:

```
frm_myform form1 = new frm_myform(); 
frm_myform.Name = "form1";
```

Comment: I know, it is not the text. I use the form name but Application.openForms returns neither null nor something else.

Comment: frm_myform form1=new frm_myform();

Comment: Then you can access the form through your `form1` variable, right?

Comment: Yes. I access it using form1 variable.

Comment: @nrtn93 I asked for complete code, because in this line you're not setting `Name` property of the form. Thats what I mentioned.

Comment: I set name property from the properties window of the form.

Comment: How did you access the property window of a dynamically generated form?