# C# Garbage Collection in windows forms

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have 2 windows forms frmMain & frmDialog. When I click a button on frmMain, frmDialog opens. Here is my code for the click event of the button:

```
frmDialog f2 = new frmDialog();

f2.Show();
```

When I keep on clicking the button, new forms appear & **don't close**. An object gets garbage collected when it goes out of scope.

**My question is:**

Why doesn't variable f2 get garbage collected when it goes out of scope?

Is it a memory leak?

Comment: Do you ever close the form ? Your question does not make it clear. Whay shouldn't "new frmDialog()" not create a new Form instance ?

Comment: Garbage collection has nothing to do with showing windows. Also, "An object gets garbage collected when it goes out of scope" is incorrect. A closer to correct statement is that "an object *becomes eligible for collection* when it can be demonstrated that no further use of that object will occur". This can be *earlier* than the end of a "scope" and also just states *eligibility*. There's no guarantee on *when* the object will be collected.

Comment: @Smartis - only so long as "you", whatever you mean by that word, isn't *also* eligible for collection.

Comment: When I close the frmMain, frmMain as well as all dialogs close

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick. When you call `Show`, the property `Visible` is set to true, which in turn calls `SetVisibleCore`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,b31b076f655b0b4b

The interesting bits are:

```
if (CalledOnLoad) {
    // VSWhidbey 518085: make sure the form is in the Application.OpenForms collection
    if (!Application.OpenFormsInternal.Contains(this)) {
        Application.OpenFormsInternalAdd(this);
    }
}
```

The form is added to a collection stored in a static property, [`Application.OpenFormsInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,1f34d9c5197d1990). Therefore, your form gets rooted and won't be eligible to garbage collection until closed (and automatically removed from that collection).

---

Following Hans Passant's comment, I played a bit with a memory dump:

```
0:000> !gcroot 000000000263d368
HandleTable:
0000000000191348 (strong handle)
-> 000000000263d368 WindowsFormsApp1.Form1

00000000001917d0 (pinned handle)
-> 00000000125f99a8 System.Object[]
-> 000000000262c9a8 System.Windows.Forms.FormCollection
-> 000000000262c9d8 System.Collections.ArrayList
-> 000000000262ca00 System.Object[]
-> 000000000263d368 WindowsFormsApp1.Form1
```

We see the `Application.OpenFormsInternal` collection (the second root), but also a strong handle that would be keeping the form alive even if it wasn't present in the collection (which [apparently could happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751748/17034)).

Comment: Looks convincing, but [it is not correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3751748/17034).  The reference is kept at a much lower level.  Look at NativeWindow.CreateHandle(), you'll find the HandleCollector class.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh. I stopped at the first root, I guess I should have dug deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is memory leak.

In C# you have something like two kinds of memory. Managed memory and unmanaged memory. Managed memory is managed by GC :) Unmanaged is not. You have to free unmanaged memory by yourself. So for example (managed):

```
{
    List<int> l = new List<int(); 
}
```

This one won't create memory leak. After **l** goes out of scope it is marked to be freed. **It is marked** not freed. It may be freed later (list destructor will be called then).

So how about unmanaged memory?

```
{
    MyForm f = new MyForm();
}
```

This is memory leak. When **f** goes out of scope, its **unmanaged memory** is not managed by GC at all. So **you have to free** it by yourself:

```
{
    MyForm f = new MyForm();
    f.ShowDialog();
    f.Dispose();
}
```

Dispose method frees all unamanaged memory. So now you may have two questions:
 1. How do I know if a class is managed or unmanaged?
It's pretty simple. You can assume that all classes that implement IDisposable interface (contain Dispose() method) are unmanaged - they are unmanaged by themselves or they consist of unmanaged classes. Especially every resources like fonts, streams, forms, database connections and so on.

2. How should I free modeless form?
   You could store a reference to that form and dispose it when it's no longer necessary. You could call Dispose in FormClosed event ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx )