# Check whether a form is loaded (even if Minimized)

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I have declared a form as

```
Private _fUpdate As frmUpdate
```

There are all kinds of solutions to check if a form is open and visible.

However, if a form is Minimized and not shown in the taskbar, it doesn't show up in `Application.OpenForms`.

Also `Form.IsHandleCreated` returns `false` with the above window state.

`If Not uForm Is Nothing` returns `True` even if the form has not yet been instanciated, so it isn't usuable as well.

Is there another way to check whether a form is loaded then a variable storing the window existance and hidden/shown state?

Comment: `Application.OpenForms` is unreliable at times.  Seems like just checking if the object var `IsNot Nothing` should work fine.

Comment: Null checking is not a good idea for this problem. When you close the form, the variable will not be null, instead the `Disposed` property of the form will be true.

Comment: About the minimized form which doesn't show in taskbar, if instead of setting `ShowInTaskBar` property you hide the form, you can trust to `Visible` property.

Comment: If I use Visible, it won't appear in OpenForms. :-(

Comment: @Plutonix When is Application.OpenForms unreliable?  tmighty: you have to post code that duplicates this issue with a minimized form not appearing in the OpenForms collection.  I can't duplicate that problem.

Comment: @LarsTech https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751748/1070452  I think it happens in other cases than those listed....I had it flake out a time or two and started not using it on principle

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do if I need to get the instance of a form from somewhere else within my application, is create a `Shared` property in your form called `Instance` or something similar and set it in the form's `Load` event.

With this instance property, you can call it from anywhere else in your application, and use the `WindowState` property of your form to check its state.

Example of the form:

```
Public Class frmUpdate
    Public Shared Property Instance As frmUpdate

    Private Sub OnLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Instance = Me
    End Sub
End Class
```

Example usage in some other method:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    If (frmUpdate.Instance.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized)
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for something built-in, not some custom solution.