# Exception message when I use "Contains" for a "Tag" of control

Tags: vb.net

Into a VB.NET project I have some controls with multiple tags, separated by commas. Into a `For Each` loop I am trying to check if those controls contain some of those tags and then do stuff. Sometimes it works, sometimes not, and I get an error message!!! Here is an example of my code..

This public sub placed into a module:

```
Public Sub AllForms_BottomButtons_Appearence()
    For Each OpenForms As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
        For Each FlowLayoutPanel As Control In OpenForms.Controls
            If FlowLayoutPanel.Tag.ToString.Contains("Something") Then
                For Each Label As Label In FlowLayoutPanel.Controls
                    If Label.Tag.ToString.Contains("Something") Then
                        'Some Code Here...
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

At second `IF` where I am trying to check if a `Label`'s tag contains something, I have no problem. But at first `IF` where I am trying to check if a `FlowLayoutPanel`'s tag contains something, I get this exception message `Object variable or With block variable not set.`

If I change my first `IF` to something else but tag, for example `If FlowLayoutPanel.Name.ToString.Contains("Something") Then`, I get no exception message and my application works fine without stop at my second `IF`.

Do you see something I can't see?

Comment: The error message tells you that a variable is not set and it only happens when you use the `Tag`. Maybe the `Tag` isn't set. You can't call `ToString` on an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Tags have been set into control's properties and for example, if I add this into my code `If TypeOf FlowLayoutPanel Is FlowLayoutPanel Then MsgBox(FlowLayoutPanel.Tag) End If` after `For Each FlowLayoutPanel As Control In OpenForms.Controls` I get message boxes with every tag of every FlowLayoutPanel control!!! So that means that tags have been set!!!

Comment: Just a little tip, it's not a great idea to use control names as variables. Although it works in your case, it can cause confusion and  possible problems. I would suggest using lbl instead of Label etc. Or loopVarLabel.

Comment: @DavidWilson: I agree my friend, but I wrote it like this just for this example!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because one (or more) of the controls you are iterating have no tag, i.e. it's null. You need to add null-checking to both of your `If`-statements to ensure that no such errors occur.

```
If FlowLayoutPanel.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso FlowLayoutPanel.Tag.ToString().Contains("Something") Then
    For Each Label As Label In FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
        If Label.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso Label.Tag.ToString().Contains("Something") Then
            'Some Code Here...
        End If
    Next
End If
```

**Error reference:** [**Object variable or With block variable not set - Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set)

As you may have noticed changed your second loop to:

```
For Each Label As Label In FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
```

This is because you shouldn't assume that every matching control (the `FlowLayoutPanel` variable) contains **only** labels. If you suddenly would've added another type of control to one of your `FlowLayoutPanel`s then your initial loop would've thrown an exception because it cannot cast that control to a `Label`.

The [**`OfType(Of TResult)` extension**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) ensures that you only iterate objects of the specified type, in this case `Label`s.

Finally, you should avoid using `Application.OpenForms`, it's buggy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751748

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me my friend!!! About `Application.OpenForms`, what can I use instead of it?

Comment: @Simonetos : Glad I could help! Instead of `Application.OpenForms` you could maintain your own list of forms that you add to/remove from whenever a form loads/closes. Make a separate class in which you create a `Public Shared` list, then modify it when needed.